# Moving mouse to pixel, clicks and keypresses Python

Tags: python, user-interface, mouse, pixel

For example, i know rgb code of pixel. And i want to move mouse on this pixel. I tried to do this on pyautogui. i get mouseposition's coordinates with `x, y = pyautogui.position()` `pyautogui.screenshot()` and `pyautogui.getpixel()` but after this i want to move my mouse to this point if mouse is somewhere far...
Also i tried to find objecy on screen with pyautogui.moveTo(pyautogui.center(pyautogui.locateOnScreen('some picture'))), but there is problem with screen and screenshot resolution. I have 24 inch monitor at home and 20 inch monitor at work, and they have diferent resolution ofc. So, my script doesn't finds object on screenshot and returns `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

It shows mouse's position on screen. Works fine.

```
x, y = pyautogui.position()
print(x, y, end='')
```

After this i am moving mouse to selected cords. Works fine too.

```
pyautogui.moveTo(x, y, duration = random.randint(2,5))
```

After this i am trying to emulate leftclick or keypress. But it does not works.

```
pyautogui.click()
```

or

```
pyautogui.keyDown('F')
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.keyUp('F')
```

And this method

```
def clickleft(x,y):
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x,y))
    sleep(randint(2,5))
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0)
    time.sleep(0.3)
    win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0)
clickleft(x, y)
```

and keyboard

```
shell.SendKeys("F")
```

After all, i heard that i need DirectInput and hardware keycodes. So i tryed.

```
def PressKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))

def ReleaseKey(hexKeyCode):
    extra = ctypes.c_ulong(0)
    ii_ = Input_I()
    ii_.ki = KeyBdInput( 0, hexKeyCode, 0x0008 | 0x0002, 0, ctypes.pointer(extra) )
    x = Input( ctypes.c_ulong(1), ii_ )
    ctypes.windll.user32.SendInput(1, ctypes.pointer(x), ctypes.sizeof(x))


while (True):
    PressKey(0x11)
    time.sleep(1)
    ReleaseKey(0x11)
    time.sleep(1)
```

But i have no result. It works fine in Notepad, but after i just LAUNCH the game, script does not works in game nor in Notepad. Macros from Razer or Bloody mice works good. But script must find some object on screen using

```
pyautogui.locateOnScreen('C:\\picture.PNG')
```

May be python can...integrate mice's macro. so i can combine simple code with macro? I have installed Nacro Py, MCPY and others, but they has no documentation and i dont know is it exactly what i need.

Comment: Emil, We can't (or won't) generally help you without showing us the script you're having the issue with.  Please post a script for us to help troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: problem is that i can't write script. And it is the reason i created topic here. I can post some screenshots with pieces of my code, but i'm sure that it is useless untill i learn to move mouse to pixel not to coordinates

Comment: We don't want screenshots with pieces of your code.  We need code (not pictures of code).  Generally, if you can't provide code, we can't provide help.  Why can't you "write script"?

Comment: edited post, added my examples.

Comment: It sounds like the clicking is actually working correctly  (If not, you could try: [Moving and clicking combined](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mouse.html#mouse-clicks).  I'm betting what isn't working is that your `.png` image isn't a pixel-perfect match for the part of the game you're wanting to click on (or even if it is, see [here](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui/issues/4)).

Comment: but it does not works even i write coods taken from pyautogui.position() function. i think game somehow blocking or not accepting 'my type' of comands. Keycodes in pyautogui module, any program keycodes. And i need hardware keycodes may be? but strange that mouse movement is working.

Comment: It sounds like you have 2 issues.  1.  It can't find the image to click on, and 2.  The click isn't registering in your game.  For #2, you could try some of the solutions listed with AutoHotKey [here](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/111737-how-to-make-ahk-work-in-most-games-the-basics/).